# Set Theoretic naming for a union property

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I am introducing a new operation for countable sets, say $\mathcal{X}(\cdot)$ is the operation. I have proved that for two sets $S_1, S_2$ we have: 
$$\mathcal
X(S_1 \cup S_1) = \mathcal{X}(S_1) \cup \mathcal{X}(S_2).$$

How can I name this property in set-theory language?

Comment: Something like linearity or linear invariance, but for sets

Comment: I don't know why, but it's not uncommon for people to tag questions literally about terminology under "notation".

Comment: it looks like a homomorphism

Comment: @AsafKaragila That's mainly for people whose primary language isn't English, couldn't find anything under 'naming' etc. and went for 'notation' mistakenly (I guess)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is distributive over unions.

Much like how $a\times(b+c)=a\times b+a\times c$ is the distributivity of $\times$ over $+$.

Comment: ah, thanks ! that helps

Comment: note that $\times$ is a binary operation and $\mathcal X$ is not

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: Do you prefer the case of scalar multiplication in vector spaces? (Which is an unary operator on the vector space.)

Comment: that's a good point, @AsafKaragila, but I will note that the definition of distributive property in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Definition) says it's for binary operators

Comment: For me, distributivity of an unary operation over a binary operation is (a kind of) linearity.